# World of Warcraft lagging using Wine

Tags: nvidia, wine, games

World of Warcraft is lagging

My PC is does not have the latest hardware. But thing is when I was running Windows I could tweak it and set it to lowest performance and the game was running just fine. But it dose not seem to work in Ubuntu. Also one thing, when I switch to desktop, and go back to the game, the freeze.

What am I doing wrong

Graphic: GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5600+ × 2
RAM: 6 GB
OStype 64-bit
Disk space, 300 GB

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the latest Nvidia drivers

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   ```
2. Open the Registry-Editor (part of the package `wine`)

   ```
   regedit
   ```
3. Create a new key

   - **Select** the path below

     ```
     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\
     ```
   - Right click and select

     <kbd>New</kbd> > <kbd>Key</kbd>
   - Use the name

     ```
     DisabledExtensions
     ```
4. Enter the value

   - Double click the cell in the table in the right pane in the column <kbd>Data</kbd>
   - and enter

     ```
     GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
     ```

   [image]
5. Use OpenGL

   - Open the file `~/.wine/drive_c/Programme/World of Warcraft/WTF/`

     ```
     nano ~/.wine/drive_c/Programme/World of Warcraft/WTF/Config.wtf
     ```
   - Add the line

     ```
     SET gxApi "opengl"
     ```
   - To deactivate anti aliasing, add

     ```
     SET ffxGlow "0"
     ```
6. Configure `wine`

   - Start with

     ```
     winecfg
     ```
   - Use the tab <kbd>Graphics</kbd>

     Activate <kbd>Allow the window manager to control the windows</kbd>

     Activate <kbd>Pixel Shader</kbd> (not in the screenshot, because it's not supported in my case)

   [image]
7. Enjoy **:)**
8. If you have more problems, try the settings below, in `~/.wine/drive_c/Programme/World of Warcraft/WTF/Config.wtf` too

   - Graphic

     ```
     SET ffxDeath "0"
     SET ffxGlow "0"
     ```
   - Neon colors

     ```
     SET pixelShaders "0"
     SET M2UsePixelShaders "1"
     SET M2UseShaders "0"
     ```
   - Sound

     ```
     SET SoundOutputSystem "1"
     SET SoundBufferSize "150"
     ```

Comment: Wow!  I would have said: [Don't even bother with this hardware](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+210&id=1169)